# create my own Scrollpane by editing ScrollpaneUI

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

i would like to create my own `scrollPane`.

it's look like this :

```
<-- |  components | -->
```

when we press in the arrows the components moves(scroll).

i can do it by create `myScrollPane extends JSCroolPane` and add two button that their action is to set the `JScrollPane`.   but i want to learn and do it with edit `scrollPaneUI`. 
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a customized toolbar for it

see these links (first try the second link and then the first link )

http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/12/05/create-a-sideway-scrolling-toolbar-using-java/
http://www.coderanch.com/t/344048/GUI/java/Scrollable-toolbar